# Put an HTML <iframe> into Ext.panel.Panel

Tags: html, iframe, extjs, iframe-app, frameset-iframe

I am trying to put an  into an ExtJS panel using html config. I have dynamically created  which I need to put in this iFrame.

Upon execution, an HTML is getting created under the iFrame but the body appears as empty. no Errors. Following is my ExtJS Panel code

```
    me.outputDataPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
     bodyStyle  : me.htmlBodyStyle,
     cls            : 'htmlView_font',
     border: 0,
     style: 'margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;'              
    });
```

On click of a button following happens

```
me.outputDataPanel.removeAll(true);
var innerHtml = '';
var Id = "SampleID";
var Name = "SampleName";
var DOB = "SampleDOB";
var Gender = "SampleGender";
var patientHeader = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>My Report</title></head><body>'+
                    '<table><tr><td style="font-size: 31pt; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; padding-left:5px;">Report</td></tr></table><br/><br/>'+
                    '<table class="table_base" style="padding-left:9px;"><tr><td class="report_m1">ID</td><td class="report_m2">'+Id+'</td></tr>'+
                    '<tr><td class="report_m1">Name</td><td class="report_m2">'+Name+'</td></tr>'+
                    '<tr><td class="report_m1">Date of Birth</td><td class="report_m2">'+DOB+'</td></tr>'+
                    '<tr><td class="report_m1">Sex</td><td class="report_m2">'+Gender+'</td></tr></table><br/><br/>'+
                    '<div id="noteText" style="padding-left:9px;">(Note) This PSD include some errors resulting from differences in the paient\'s actual size and position compared with the model.</div>'; 
innerHtml+=patientHeader;   
innerHtml+='</body></html>';
me.outputDataPanel.add({
        bodyStyle: 'overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto',
        style: 'border:1px solid #b7bcc4;',
        height: "100%",
        //html : '<p>test 123</p>'
        html: '<iframe id="frameReportPanel" name="frameReportPanelName" style="width:100%; height:100%;" align="middle" isShow="true" name="frame" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 srcdoc="'+innerHtml+'"></iframe>'
});
```

Didn't understand what exactly is going wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Ext.ux.IFrame](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.ux.IFrame)? It's a true Ext JS component, so it may just make your life easier.

Comment: This is a suggestion, not an answer to the question. Should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you don't really have to use an iFrame. You could just use a container and to update the html on a container you just have to use the `update` function. You can look at the documentation [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-update).

However, if you want to load an external web page/remote content, you might want to use `loader` property of the component/container. You can find the docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-loader).

Comment: This is also not an answer to the question. Suggestions should be comments, not answers.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. In his code, he is not using `Ext.ux.IFrame`. It's just a panel, you can always use `update` function to update the html.

Comment: That is correct, I almost added a comment saying that, but since that's not the problem at hand, I didn't mention it

Comment: Hi Dumbledore, sorry for the late response, I was on vacation. I need an iFrame only to put my dynamic HTML code in it so that I can do a window.print on it. With the panel that you have mentioned, I was able to do a var printId = me.outputFramePanel.el.id; $('#'+printId).printElement(); http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/. Problem with this is that on print I am getting the visible part of the panel only for print and instead of printing everything inside the panel, I get a scroll-bar print on the screen. That's why switched to iFrame. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly escaping the contents of your `srcdoc` attribute. Since you are quoting it with double quotes, any double quotes in the HTML must be escaped.

```
innerHtml.replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
```

Comment: Hi Juan, Sorry for the late response, I was on vacation. I tried what you have mentioned. It's executing with no errors but the body of the table is appearing empty, It seems to work till the point where no data has been added dynamically. I need to put dynamically created HTML in this so that I can do a window.print on this iFrame. Any ideas?

Comment: Try waiting for the onload handler

Comment: Didn't work :( It seems to me that if you are trying to put HTML into an iframe it needs to be complete as a wholesome and be available. Need to figure out another way of doing it.